# How to check that installed android application in PAID or FREE?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I have created an Android Application in that I want to check that installed android application is paid or free programmatically when app starts.

I can't found any help related to my question.

Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is to examine fields in the Android Manifest or the Package Name and make your determination from there. You could use the Market API but that will be a lot of work and fail when the network isn't available (and require a bunch of permissions.) For example, include the word 'paid' in @package and check for that.

Comment: @CoryTrese, thanks for suggestion, I will try using your answer.